# Why won't node update on Ubuntu, but has on Powershell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, ubuntu, npm

Every time I start my ubuntu terminal I get this message saying the latest version of npm does not support my current version of node(15.13.0), but I went to [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and installed v 16.13.0 yesterday and it installed fine in powershell but hasn't updated in ubuntu. I've tried running

`sudo npm cache clean -f && sudo npm install -g n && sudo n stable`

and got the following

`npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s found 0 vulnerabilities npm notice npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.1.0 -> 8.1.4 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.1.4 npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.1.4 to update! npm notice installed : v16.13.0 (with npm 8.1.0) awilbur@LAPTOP-ND9AON1L:/$ node -v v15.13.0`
I've restarted my terminal and computer but nothing changed. Can anyone help?

[image: node ubuntu version]

[image: node powershell version]